# Image upload using PHP in flutter

Tags: php, flutter, image

I have created an app in flutter that uses SQL database and I am using PHP as my server side language to upload data from the app to the SQL server. But there is a problem when it comes to the uploading of image, the image is being uploaded but in only shows *0 bytes*

PHP code:

```
$profdir = 'Mobile-profile-img/';
$fileName = $profileCode . '.jpg';
file_put_contents($profdir.$fileName, base64_decode($profileimg));

$profimgurl = "https://e4psmap.com/Mobile-app/$profdir$fileName";
```

Flutter code:

```
try{
  final profimage = File(image);
  final housimage = File(himage);

  String proftobase64 = base64Encode(await profimage.readAsBytes());
  String housetobase64 = base64Encode(await housimage.readAsBytes());


  String urls = api_config.sync_profile;
  var res = await http.post(Uri.parse(urls), headers: {"Accept":"application/json"},
      body:{
        "hh_id": id,
        "prof_image":proftobase64,
        ... etc.
 });
      var auth = jsonDecode(res.body);
      return auth;
```

it sends base 64 and the base 64 image will be decoded in PHP

[image of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad0Yg.png)

Comment: how are you creating the $profileimg variable?

Answer (score 0):

You might try checking the permissions on the 'Mobile-profile-img' directory and ensuring that the web server has write access to it.

You could also try printing out the value of '$fileName' to ensure that it is being set correctly.

If neither of these work, you could try debugging the PHP code by adding some debugging statements to print out the contents of '$profdir', '$fileName.'

Also, you might try checking PHP server error logs by using this command or similar to this:

tail -n 50 /var/log/apache2/error.log